# Using Personalization Web Campaigns with Offline Data

Tags: personalization

What I'm trying to do: We want to personalize a web experience for users based on our funnel data that is updated in our CRM (Microsoft Dynamics). Users that are in different statuses would receive different CTA's on the website to move them to the next step.

Where I'm at: We use marketing cloud so I was able to get the status data I need into Personalization using Automation Studio. I believe my next step is to be able to use identity attributes and the unified profile to connect a user that is on the site with their status, assuming they have one.

My question: How do I do this? My current thought is to find a way to collect the ProfileID that Personalization creates so we can pass that info to our system, so when that info is passed back to Personalization it can merge the profiles and allow for the status to update the CTA.

Am I on the right track, or is there a better way to do this? I tried finding documentation related to this but was unsuccessful.

Thanks in advance!